# opening an excel protected sheet using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to open an excel file using c# however visual studio is giving this OLEDB exception: "Could not decrypt file." When opening a non prtected excel file the code works fine.

Hereunder is my code:

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + s + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(conn);
        objConn.Open();

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", objConn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
```

I found the following website which suggests a workaround for vb but I couldn't get it to work in C#. [VBA excel](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/how-to-open-password-protected-excel-workbook)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an OpenSource library like [OoXmlCrypto](http://code.google.com/p/ooxmlcrypto/) to decrypt the password protected file, otherwise you can still use the Microsoft Interop official library that support password :

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

WorkbookObject.Password = password;
```

Otherwise the simplest way in your case, you can add the password property to the connection string of your OLeDb provider :

```
string conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + s + ";Password=password;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
```